# Android Unit Tests Requiring Context

Tags: database, android, unit-testing

I am writing my first Android database backend and I'm struggling to unit test the creation of my database.

Currently the problem I am encountering is obtaining a valid Context object to pass to my implementation of SQLiteOpenHelper.  Is there a way to get a Context object in a class extending TestCase?  The solution I have thought of is to instantiate an Activity in the setup method of my TestCase and then assigning the Context of that Activity to a field variable which my test methods can access...but it seems like there should be an easier way.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You might try switching to [AndroidTestCase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/AndroidTestCase.html).  From looking at the docs, it seems like it should be able to provide you with a valid Context to pass to SQLiteOpenHelper.

Edit:
Keep in mind that you probably have to have your tests setup in an "Android Test Project" in Eclipse, since the tests will try to execute on the emulator (or real device).

Comment: when extending AndroidTestCase and then calling `this.getContext()`, `null` is returned.  is that how it's supposed to work?  I expected a rich Context to be returned that would work with SQLite

Comment: AndroidTestCase is now deprecated, and it is recommended to use InstrumentationRegistry instead.

Comment: `android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry` is now depreciated as well. Google is depreciating stuff faster than you can type a stackoverfow comment.

Answer (score 54):

You can use [`InstrumentationRegistry`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/InstrumentationRegistry.html) methods to get a Context:

`InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()` - provides the application `Context` of the target application.

`InstrumentationRegistry.getContext()` - provides the `Context` of this Instrumentation’s package.

---

For AndroidX use `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext()` or `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getContext()`.

New API for AndroidX:
[ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/core/app/ApplicationProvider#getApplicationContext())

Comment: what dependency AndroidJUnit4.class comes from?

Comment: ditto on needing a more complete example.

Comment: This wouldn't be a unit test, but an integration test.

Comment: @birdy how can I use this together with JUnit5?

Comment: Update: use `ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()` instead

Comment: Anybody got the full syntax for Kotlin for using `getApplicationContext`?

Comment: @Martin Here is the link for kotlin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605611/get-context-of-test-project-in-android-junit-test-case/75404479#75404479

Answer (score 24):

Your test is not a Unit test!!!

When you need

- Context
- Read or Write on storage
- Access Network
- Or change any config to test your function

You are not writing a unit test.

You need to write your test in `androidTest` package

Comment: You mean it's not a *local* test (but an *instrumented* test). A test in the `androidTest` package can very well be a unit test.

Comment: how did you come to this idea or where did you read that, many times in unit test mock classes don't really do the job because they are fake but we to test something real

Comment: Really, this is a comment to the question, not an answer to the question.
Also it's highly opinionated which is not appropriate for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 6):

Using the `AndroidTestCase:getContext()` method only gives a stub Context in my experience. For my tests, I'm using an empty activity in my main app and getting the `Context` via that. Am also extending the test suite class with the `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` class. Seems to work for me.

```
public class DatabaseTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<EmptyActivity>
    EmptyActivity activity;
    Context mContext = null;
    ...
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        activity = getActivity();
        mContext = activity;
    }
    ... //tests to follow
}
```

What does everyone else do?

Answer (score 5):

You can derive from [**MockContext**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/mock/MockContext.html) and return for example a [MockResources](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/mock/MockResources.html) on `getResources()`, a valid [ContentResolver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html) on `getContentResolver()`, etc. That allows, with some pain, some *unit tests*.

The alternative is to run for example [**Robolectric**](http://robolectric.org/) which simulates a whole Android OS. Those would be for *system tests*: It's a lot slower to run.

Answer (score 3):

You should use ApplicationTestCase or ServiceTestCase.

Answer (score 2):

Extending AndroidTestCase and calling AndroidTestCase:getContext() has worked fine for me to get Context for and use it with an SQLiteDatabase.

The only niggle is that the database it creates and/or uses   will be the same as the one used by the production application so you will probably want to use a different filename for both

eg.

```
  public static final String    NOTES_DB      = "notestore.db";
  public  static final String   DEBUG_NOTES_DB = "DEBUG_notestore.db";
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize context like this in your Test File

private val context = mock(Context::class.java)

Answer (score 0):

First Create Test Class under (androidTest).

Now use following code:

```
public class YourDBTest extends InstrumentationTestCase {

private DBContracts.DatabaseHelper db;
private RenamingDelegatingContext context;

@Override
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    context = new RenamingDelegatingContext(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext(), "test_");
    db = new DBContracts.DatabaseHelper(context);
}

@Override
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    db.close();
    super.tearDown();
}

@Test
public void test1() throws Exception {
    // here is your context
    context = context;
}}
```

Comment: _“This class was deprecated in API level 24.
Use InstrumentationRegistry instead. New tests should be written using the AndroidX Test Library.”_