# Accessing application context from TestSuite in Setup() before calling getActivity()

Tags: android, unit-testing

I have an `Activity` that pulls an object from an `Application` extended class (application context) from within the `OnCreate()` method.

When unit testing this activity, the object needed isn't there because it is populated from a previous Activity and stored in the above mentioned application context.

Needless to say, when I call `getActivity()` from within my `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` extended test case I get a null pointer exception.

How can I populate the context before an activity is started and have it available to that `Activity`?

**Updated:**
After a bit of digging I found: `this.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext()` and then cast it to the type of my `Application` extended class. But I get a class cast exception and the trace points to this:

```
04-04 21:02:27.036: INFO/TestRunner(431): started: testIt(edu.rockies.rockies.activity.courses.test.TopicTest)
04-04 21:02:27.126: INFO/TestRunner(431): failed: testIt(edu.rockies.rockies.activity.courses.test.TopicTest)
04-04 21:02:27.126: INFO/TestRunner(431): ----- begin exception -----
04-04 21:02:27.136: INFO/TestRunner(431): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.ApplicationContext
04-04 21:02:27.136: INFO/TestRunner(431):     at edu.rockies.rockies.activity.courses.test.TopicTest.setUp(TopicTest.java:27)
04-04 21:02:27.136: INFO/TestRunner(431):     at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:125)
04-04 21:02:27.136: INFO/TestRunner(431):     at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
04-04 21:02:27.136: INFO/TestRunner(431):     at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
04-04 21:02:27.136: INFO/TestRunner(431):     at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
04-04 21:02:27.136: INFO/TestRunner(431):     at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:118)
04-04 21:02:27.136: INFO/TestRunner(431):     at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
04-04 21:02:27.136: INFO/TestRunner(431):     at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
04-04 21:02:27.136: INFO/TestRunner(431):     at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:430)
04-04 21:02:27.136: INFO/TestRunner(431):     at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1447)
04-04 21:02:27.136: INFO/TestRunner(431): ----- end exception -----
04-04 21:02:27.156: INFO/TestRunner(431): finished: testIt(edu.rockies.rockies.activity.courses.test.TopicTest)
```

`this.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext()` is supposed to return an object of type context.  But I get the `android.app.ApplicationContext` class cast exeption which doesn't make sense.

**Update 2:**

I did some more research and discovered this for [android.app.Application](http://www.androidjavadoc.com/m3-rc37a/index.html?android/app/Application.html)

```
java.lang.Object
    android.content.Context
        android.app.ApplicationContext
            android.app.Application
```

But Google's own Android Javadoc refers to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html):

```
java.lang.Object
    android.content.Context
        android.content.ContextWrapper
            android.app.Application
```

What's going on?  Something's not right.

**Update 3:**

I have replaced the following line of code:

```
this.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext();
```

with this line of code.

```
this.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getApplicationContext();
```

Although the context resolves properly, it doesn't seem to be the same context as the activity's.

Comment: Did you try calling `getActivity().getApplication()`?

Comment: I can't because the activity's OnCreate() method depends on data being in the context already.  Calling getActivity() essentially calls the OnCreate() method which fails and thus generates a Null Pointer Exception.  Hence my dilemma.

Comment: Ok, my tests are running fine this morning. Not sure what's changed, but the latest update above (Update 3) seems to have resolved the issue.

Comment: Your Update 3 made my first test work, but the second test in the class still failed. It worked when I left the call to getApplicationContext() out.. But Why? :|

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Ok, this issue is resolved.  To get access to the context before getActivity() has been called you need to call this function:

```
Context context = this.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getApplicationContext();
```

Comment: This is not so simple or maybe things have changed:
I found out that

    this.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext()
returns exactly my application context (I know this for sure because I have custom "MyApplication" class) AND 

.getApplicationContext()

returns null. So my code which retrieves application context adapts for this case also, see https://github.com/andstatus/andstatus/blob/master/src/org/andstatus/app/data/MyPreferences.java , public static Context initialize(Context context_in, ... object );
- the context_in has .getApplicationContext() if called from the test classes

Answer (score 12):

With the newer UI testing framework `getInstrumentation()` is no longer available. One way to get hold of the `Application` object is to cast the application `Context`:

```
Application app = 
        (Application) InstrumentationRegistry
                .getTargetContext()
                .getApplicationContext();
```

Comment: I need application and with your code i get this error: android.app.ContextImpl cannot be cast to android.app.Application

Answer (score 5):

You can get the application context using the `androidx.test.core.app.ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()`. Cast that to your application and it should be the right context.

Answer (score 3):

You can call the static method for the Context:

```
Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
```

More details can be found here:
https://developer.android.com/training/testing/integration-testing/index.html

Answer (score 3):

In kotlin `val context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context` worked for me.

Comment: You might use `ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()` as well. Its a wrapper around `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: **target context** is better that context: `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext`

Answer (score 2):

Always use `this.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext()` to access the context of the application.

`this.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getApplicationContext()`
is not same as `this.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext()`

I was running the automation in 4.0.X versions and most of the time `getApplicationContext()` was returning null context.

Answer (score -2):

Keep in mind we need some of the following, the test is androidTest and not unit.

- Context
- Read or Write on storage
- Access Network
- Or change any config to test your function

---

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class SomeInstrumentedTest {
    private val appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext

    @Test
    fun useAppContext() {
        // Context of the app under test.
        Assert.assertEquals("your.package", appContext.packageName)
    }
}
```

[unit vs androidTest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56514421/5279996)