# Constructor Undefined Error - Java

Tags: java, android, constructor

Am trying call a method from another class which is present in different files.

Main File :

```
public class Test extends AndroidTestCase {
    mTestUtils = new TestUtils(this, TAG, OUTPUT_FILE);
```

Second File :

```
public class TestUtils {
    public TestUtils(Context context, String tag, String outputFile) {

        mContext = context;
        mTag = tag;
        mOutputFile = outputFile;
    }
}
```

It throws Constructor undefined error.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: how are tag and output_file defined in your test class?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Your first snippet of code wouldn't compile for *various* reasons, we don't know the types of `TAG` or `OUTPUT_FILE`, nor have you included the full error text.

Comment: `Context context` - does `AndroidTestCase` extend resp. implement `Context`?

Comment: As a side note `Public class Test` should be `public class Test`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are doing

```
TestUtils(this, TAG, OUTPUT_FILE);
```

but `this` is not a context in that case.

the method `getContext()` will provide you that, just look the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/AndroidTestCase.html)

Comment: might be helpful to explain how signatures work. But this does answer the question.

Comment: @ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ this was the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the signature of `TestUtils` constructor takes object of type `Context` and when you do this in `Test` class

```
new TestUtils(this, TAG, OUTPUT_FILE);
```

you're not passing `Context` object

instead of `this` you should pass `Context` object

checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095695/android-unit-tests-requiring-context) question